# Expandable Listview with ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>

Tags: android, string, arraylist, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I want to use the CarList as childList, so that the HashMap is a row of the list and the group string is the header. How can I achieve to group them together. And I also need an adapter to use these.

The following code is what I have so far.

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> CarList;

            static final String TAG_URLS = "urls";
            static final String TAG_ID = "id";
            static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
            static final String TAG_PIC = "pic";
            String group;

    CarList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

List<Cars> cars = db.getAllCars();       
String group = "Cars";
        for (Cars cn : cars) {

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                String id = String.valueOf(cn.getID());
                                String name = cn.getName();
                                String urls = cn.getUrls();
                                String pic = cn.getPic();

                                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                                map.put(TAG_URLS, urls);
                                map.put(TAG_PIC, pic);

                                CarList.add(map);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to have 3 levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use different value types you can use the next pattern:

Create a value object, that will have all the information for all the view types, lets call it `MyDataItem`. Than create an arrayList of 'MyDataItem'. Make sure that one of 'MyDataItem' property will be a type, so can tell the difference between header and inner item, what ever your structure are.

That you can use the next methods of BaseAdapter to deal with that:

```
        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return super.getViewTypeCount();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return super.getItemViewType(position);
        }
```

This will allow you to manage several types of views in one list. You can find more information on [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#androidlists_inputtype) manual.